# hook_field_presave() isn't getting called

Tags: hooks, entities

**Summary**

I need to edit some data before it gets saved, and `hook_field_presave()` looks like exactly what I need, but it doesn't get called for some reason.

**The Scenario**

I'd like to edit data coming from changes to the location field ([location module](http://drupal.org/project/location)), so that I can look up latitude and longitude information when none is provided and make sure it gets saved.

**The implementation**

At the moment I'm just adding the hook to the location.module for testing purposes before moving them into a separate module. The code I'm using is this:

```
function location_field_presave($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, &$items) {
  watchdog('location', 'testing location_field_presave', array(), WATCHDOG_NOTICE);
}
```

However, the dblog is never updated with my message; the code never runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are editing an enabled module, you need to first disable, and then re-enable it. Drupal saves in cache the list of hooks implemented by modules; the one I described is the way to force Drupal to update that cache.

[hook_field_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_presave/7) is invoked for the module implementing the field; the other modules should implement [hook_field_attach_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_presave/7). If the Location module is not implementing the field, it should implement `hook_field_attach_presave()`, which is what your module should do too.

The documentation is not much clear about this; but looking at [field_attach_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_presave/7) is a little more clear what happens.

```
function field_attach_presave($entity_type, $entity) {
  _field_invoke('presave', $entity_type, $entity);

  // Let other modules act on presaving the entity.
  module_invoke_all('field_attach_presave', $entity_type, $entity);
}
```

[_field_invoke()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/_field_invoke/7) invokes the hook for the module implementing the field; [module_invoke_all()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke_all/7) invokes the hook implemented by any module.

That is why the documentation for `hook_field_presave()` says, "Define custom presave behavior for this module's field types."

Comment: if other modules should be using hook_field_attach_presave(), then how would they go about changing data before saving it? I don't see any parameters passed by reference in the function definition.

Comment: They need to get the field data from the `$entity` object.

Comment: I see that the data is there, but how can I preserve my changes? Or am I expected to return the `$entity` object?

Comment: @JoBu1324 `$entity` is an object, and for the most part objects are passed by reference in PHP. Any changes you make to that object will persist outside the scope of your function

Comment: @JoBu1324 See [Objects and references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php).

Comment: Just for reference, I found [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_get_items/7) in the API, which helped me bypass an indepth examination of the `$entity` object.