# hook_field_attach_presave not saving - user profile field

Tags: hooks, users, entities

**EDIT:** As per a suggestion below, I tried using hook_field_presave, but couldn't access any parameters of the field. I then tried hook_field_attach_presave, but my alterations aren't being saved. My current module code is :

```
function module_field_attach_presave($entity_type, $entity) {
  $field = $entity->field_user_location;
  $locality = $field['und'][0]['locality'];
  $locality = ucwords(strtolower($locality));
  dpm($locality);
  }
```

The transformation is present when `Locality` prints out via `dpm`, but the transformation is not saved to the field itself. Any idea why?

**ORIGINAL:** I'm using an AddressField field in my user profiles, but I'd like to make sure that the cities that users enter are correctly capitalized. How can I do this?

I'm assuming it's some implementation of `str_replace`, but I don't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to implement [hook_field_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_presave/7). You can find out from the parameters passed in if it's being invoked for an address field saved to a user account and do the necessary transformation on the 'locality' of the address field value in the `$items` array.

Comment: As per http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52448/hook-field-presave-isnt-getting-called, it seems like I need to use `hook_field_attach_presave` since the field is being implemented by another module. However, with that hook I do not have access to `$items`, or anything besides `$entity` and `$entity_type`. None of my changes are persisting through the save though when I try and access the locality information through the field via `$entity`. Any suggestions? When I just use `hook_field_presave`, I can't even `dpm` any of the parameters.